# Clojure: get list of regex matches

Tags: regex, clojure

Perhaps I'm going about this all wrong, but I'm trying to get all the matches in a string for a particular regex pattern. I'm using `re-matcher` to get a Match object, which I pass to `re-find`, giving me (`full-string-match`, `grouped-text`) pairs. How would I get a sequence of all the matches produced by the Match object?

In Clojuresque Python, it would look like:

```
pairs = []
match = re-matcher(regex, line)

while True:
    pair = re-find(match)
    if not pair: break
    pairs.append(pair)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You probably want to use the built in `re-seq` and Clojure's built in regex literal. Don't mess with underlying java objects unless you really have too.

```
(doc re-seq)
```

```
clojure.core/re-seq
([re s])
  Returns a lazy sequence of successive matches of pattern in string,
  using java.util.regex.Matcher.find(), each such match processed with
  re-groups.
```

For example:

```
user> (re-seq #"the \w+" "the cat sat on the mat")
("the cat" "the mat")
```

In answer to the follow-up comment, group captures will result in a vector of strings with an element for each part of the group in a match:

```
user> (re-seq #"the (\w+(t))" "the cat sat on the mat")
(["the cat" "cat" "t"] ["the mat" "mat" "t"])
```

You can extract a specific element by taking advantage of the elegant fact that vectors are functions of their indices.

```
user> (defn extract-group [n] (fn [group] (group n)))
#'user/extract-group
user> (let [matches (re-seq #"the (\w+(t))" "the cat sat on the mat")]
       (map (extract-group 1) matches))
("cat" "mat")
```

Or you can destructure the matches (here using a `for` macro to go over all the matches but this could also be done in a `let` or function argument binding):

```
user> (dorun 
        (for [[m1 m2 m3] (re-seq #"the (\w+(t))" "the cat sat on the mat")]  
          (do (println "m1:" m1) 
              (println "m2:" m2) 
              (println "m3:" m3))))
m1: the cat
m2: cat
m3: t
m1: the mat
m2: mat
m3: t
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, but I'm getting a different result: a vector of lists, not a vector of strings.

Comment: Did you mean a 'sequence of vectors'? That is what would be returned if you have group capturing in your regex. I have added some more examples above.

Comment: You're right: I must have meant 'sequence of vectors'. Your examples have cleared things up for me. Thanks.